# Continuity conditions for multivariate functions.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

Is the following true ? A proof or counter-example or reference would be nice.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous at $(0,0)$ if and only if
if for all $a, b$, the limits $$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} f(at,bt)$$ exist are all are equal.

Can the condition of approach in all directions be weakened to the equallty of approach along two distinct lines ? 
One direction is of course trivial.

I think it is implicitly assumed that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no.  For example, $f(0,0)=0$ and 
$$ f(x,y) =  \frac{2x^2y}{x^4+y^2} $$
You can see $t \mapsto (t,mt)$ gives $f(t,mt) = \frac{2mt^3}{t^4+m^2t^2} =\frac{2mt}{t^2+m^2}$ hence all linear paths to $(0,0)$ give trivial path limits for $f$. However, $f$ is not continuous as is easily seen by studying quadratic paths. For those, differing quadratics will yield different path limits. Consider $t \mapsto (t,mt^2)$ note $f(t,mt^2) = \frac{2mt^4}{t^4+m^2t^4} = \frac{2m}{1+m^2}$. Clearly different $m$ give different quadratic path limits for $f$. But, if $f$ was continuous at $(0,0)$ then **all** path limits must converge to the same value. Hence, $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ despite the temptation to ascertain such from the linear data.

Naturally, examples exist for other classes of paths. This is a subtle issue.

Comment: Great example ! Thanks for this.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus glad to be of service, notice the 8-th and 9-th graphs at http://www.supermath.info/ZooOfMathematicalCreatures.html are illustrations of the calculations I give above.