# A limit two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{(a+x)(b+y)}-\mathrm{e}^{ab}-b\mathrm{e}^{ab}x-a\mathrm{e}^{ab}y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$

Comment: Let $x = y$ for your limit

Comment: That doesn't prove anything @VarunIyer, except for that single path.

Comment: But if you can prove it for more than one path, you can prove the limit exists and it equals 0

Comment: If by more than one path you mean every path, then yes.

Comment: not even if by all paths does the limit exist, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/829201/149912

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove that $f(x,y)=e^{(a+x)(b+y)}$ differentiable on $(0,0)$. So we have(by definition) $$f(x,y)-f(0,0)=f'_x(0,0)x+f'_y(0,0)y+o(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}).$$

Comment: You should prove that the function is differentiable $\textbf{of course}$ directly only with the definition.

Comment: This is the right way to solve this question.

Comment: I know it. Realy, when I like prove that function $\mathrm{e}^{xy}$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ then I had to show that $\textbf{the limit}$ is $0$. Now, what do you say????

Comment: Please, you prove that $\mathrm{e}^{xy}$ is differentiable in all $(a,b)$ by the definition directly.

Comment: It has continuous partial derivatives, so it is differentiable (Do you know that theorem? If not, you can try to prove it or find it in every calculus book that has a chapter about functions of many variables).

Answer (score 0):

Although I do believe that this should be considered an easy result from usual calculation rules, if you really want to do it by hand, use polar coordinates. It's usually easier to look at these problems in polar coordinates, because you go from 2 variables to just one.

Here:
 $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{(a+x)(b+y)}-\mathrm{e}^{ab}-b\mathrm{e}^{ab}x-a\mathrm{e}^{ab}y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}= \lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(a+r\cos\theta)(b+r\sin\theta)-\exp(ab)(1+br\cos\theta + ar\sin \theta)}{r} = ...$$